# Other than a "15 member vote", can a specific kind of action compel legislators to physically sit in their House?

Tags: united-states, legislative-process

## Background

Several articles have been talking about the [implications](https://www.npr.org/2019/11/06/776182132/a-disaster-impeachment-could-sideline-senators-in-2020-presidential-campaign) of a [potential](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2020-election/impeachment-haunts-campaign-trail-candidates-compete-against-bigger-story-n1075801) [Impeachment trial](https://www.politico.com/news/2019/10/31/impeachment-democratic-candidadtes-063478) on the 2020 Democratic Primary.  The implication that seems to repeat itself applies to senators running in the primary.  Namely, if an impeachment trial were to occur, these Senators would likely have to be recalled to the Senate to participate in the trial.  As NPR writes:

> That would keep those six candidates stuck in Washington, acting as jurors – and out of Iowa and other key early states — in the critical final weeks before the caucuses.
>
> "We will have to convene every day, six days out of seven," Senate Majority Leader Mitch McConnell recently told reporters. President Bill Clinton's 1999 impeachment trial lasted more than a month. The only other impeachment trial in U.S. history, President Andrew Johnson's, ran on and off for more than two months.

This made me more curious about instances of required attendance in the legislative branch.

### House Document 110-49

The [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedures_of_the_United_States_Congress) on the Procedures of Congress does not mention anything about required physical attendance for the duration of any one specific procedure. In fact it mentions this about attendance, cited from [House Document 110-49](https://www.congress.gov/resources/display/content/How+Our+Laws+Are+Made+-+Learn+About+the+Legislative+Process):

> SYSTEM OF LIGHTS AND BELLS
>
> Due to the diverse nature of daily tasks that they have to perform, it is not practicable for Members to be present in the House or Senate Chamber at every minute that the body is in session. Furthermore, many of the routine matters do not require the personal attendance of all the Members. A system consisting of electric lights and bells or buzzers located in various parts of the Capitol Building and House and Senate Office Buildings alerts Members to certain occurrences in the House and Senate Chambers.

However, digging further in the cites document mentions this about compulsory attendance that is voted on:

> QUORUM CALLS AND ROLL CALLS
>
> Article I, Section 5, of the Constitution provides that a majority of each House constitutes a quorum to do business and authorizes a smaller number than a quorum to compel the attendance of absent Members. In order to fulfill this constitutional responsibility, the rules of the House provide alternative procedures for quorum calls in the House and the Committee of the Whole.
>
> In the absence of a quorum, 15 Members may initiate a call of the House to compel the attendance of absent Members. Such a call of the House must be ordered by a majority vote. A call of the House is then ordered and the call is taken by electronic device or by response to the alphabetical call of the roll of Members. Absent Members have a minimum of 15 minutes from the ordering of the call of the House by electronic device to have their presence recorded. If sufficient excuse is not offered for their absence, they may be sent for by the Sergeant-at-Arms and their attendance secured and retained. The House then determines the conditions on which they may be discharged. Members who voluntarily appear are, unless the House otherwise directs, immediately admitted to the Hall of the House and must report their names to the Clerk to be entered on the Journal as present. Compulsory attendance or arrest of Members has been rare in modern practice.

## Question

Other than the 15 vote procedure mentioned above, are there other specific kinds of legislation or actions that compel legislators to physically sit in their chamber?